# displaying data from a DB according to my choice on a template

Tags: php, templates

i am new in PHP i am building an e comerce website with a  template my motive is to display all the products  in my template from my database table and my aproch is that i call all the data of particular columnt  in one arayy and then display it into my suitable place of template but its givving an error

//my php code

```
<?php
    $name = array();
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','********'); 
    mysql_select_db('shopper');

    $result = mysql_query ('SELECT * FROM products WHERE availibilty > 0 ');
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0 )
    { 
        echo "there is nothing to display ";  
    }
    else
    { 
        while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $get_row['name'] = true;
            $name[] = $get_row; 
            echo $name[0] ;
        }
    }
?>
```

//error is

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp\www\shopper_new\index.php on line 15
```

can any body suggest me what is the better aproch i dont want all the data af particular coloumn all together.

Comment: try to use  `$name[] = $get_row[];`

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in C:\wamp\www\shopper_new\index.php on line 14
 by using this above error is found

Comment: the above code works fine for me

Comment: but why not for me ? :(

Answer (score 0):

use array_push to insert value into array.

```
while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   $get_row['name'] = true;
   array_push($name, $get_row['name']);            
}
```